# Why dataframe column datatype is not changing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a small code to test how to change datatype of a column of a DataFrame in Python (Version 3.8.5 and running the code in Jupyter Notebook). But it is not changing the datatype. Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':['20+', '21.5', '19+', '18.6']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Age_Corrected"] = df["Age"].str.replace("+","")
df
df["Age_Corrected"].astype("float")
df.info()
```

But I am not getting Age_Corrected as float. It is still showing object. The result I am getting from df.info() is given below.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   Name           4 non-null      object
 1   Age            4 non-null      object
 2   Age_Corrected  4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Check out the `astype` section of the accepted answer of the linked duplicate. As the answers below notes, `astype` is not an in-place operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not change because you don't reaffect the column. Try this one

```
df["Age_Corrected"] = df["Age_Corrected"].astype("float")
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to do

`df["Age_Corrected"] = df["Age_Corrected"].astype("float")`